# Gcloud app deploy cannot ignore Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, google-app-engine, gcloud

I usually deploy my **NodeJS** app to Google App Engine and ignore all docker assets when deploying by a `.gcloudignore` file as below:

```
.git
.gitignore
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
nginx/
redis-data/
.vscode/
.DS_Store
.prettierrc
README.md
node_modules/
.env
```

Last week I have successfully deployed my app to App Engine without any problems. But today (without any changes except source code) it failed and threw me an Error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) There is a Dockerfile in the current directory, and the runtime field in /Users/tranphongbb/Works/unstatic/habitify-annual-report-backend/app.yaml is currently set to [runtime: nodejs]. To use your Dockerfile to build a custom runtime, set the runtime field to [runtime: custom]. To continue using the [nodejs] runtime, please remove the Dockerfile from this directory.
```

Even when removing the `.gcloudignore` file and go with the `skip_files` option in `app.yaml`, it still failed.

**My source tree**:

```
.dockerignore
.eslintrc.json
.gcloudignore
.gitignore
.prettierrc
.vscode
Dockerfile
README.md
app.yaml
docker-compose.yml
nginx
package.json
src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your issue by cloning both Node.js App Engine Flex Quickstart and adding a Dockerfile to the same folder as the app.yaml file.
Indeed, I received the same error message as you did. But I was able to see that if I move the Dockerfile to a different directory, the deploy succeeds. It seems that gcloud app deploy doesn't respect the .gcloudignore file.

For node.js in the Flexible Environment, there’s no skip_files entry in the [App Engine Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref).

To ignore your files defined in .gcloudignore file, please run the command `gcloud beta app deploy` which worked for me to ignore the Dockerfile when using Nodejs Runtime in app.yaml or you can use `gcloud app deploy` command but move your Dockerfile to another directory.

Comment: Moving Dockerfile to another directory is not a good way, but I have none left. Thanks. I will accept your answer :D.

Comment: Did you try to deploy with gcloud beta app deploy maintaining the Dockerfile in the same directory?

Comment: It uploaded over 20k files to the cloud, I supposed that will be the node_modules folder. Therefore, it's just following the app.yaml defined runtime, and not respect to anything else.

Comment: I have reopened this [Public Issue Tracker request](https://issuetracker.google.com/139940112) on your behalf where the Google Cloud Platform Team will investigate the issue. Please keep track of the issue and their you will be updated regarding this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `.gcloudignore` file is to avoid certain files to be uploaded to App Engine, Cloud Functions, etc, deployments which is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore). When using `gcloud app deploy` this command will notice if there is a `Dockerfile` and will correlate that in the `app.yaml` there is set `runtime: custom`. In case that condition is not meet, you'll get a similar error message as follows:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) There is a Dockerfile in the current directory, and the runtime field in path/app.yaml is currently set to [runtime: nodejs]. To use your Dockerfile to build a custom runtime, set the runtime field to [runtime: custom]. To continue using the [nodejs] runtime, please remove the Dockerfile from this directory.
```

Now the last question, why does this work with `gcloud beta app deploy` and not with `gcloud app deploy`?

Checking at the source code of the Cloud SDK which can be viewed by anyone, the `gcloud app deploy` has the following code which makes the verification mentioned before:

```
if info.runtime == 'custom':
    if has_dockerfile and has_cloudbuild:
      raise CustomRuntimeFilesError(
          ('A custom runtime must have exactly one of [{}] and [{}] in the '
           'source directory; [{}] contains both').format(
               config.DOCKERFILE, runtime_builders.Resolver.CLOUDBUILD_FILE,
               source_dir))
    elif has_dockerfile:
      log.info('Using %s found in %s', config.DOCKERFILE, source_dir)
      return False
    elif has_cloudbuild:
      log.info('Not using %s because cloudbuild.yaml was found instead.',
               config.DOCKERFILE)
      return True
    else:
      raise NoDockerfileError(
          'You must provide your own Dockerfile when using a custom runtime. '
          'Otherwise provide a "runtime" field with one of the supported '
          'runtimes.')
  else:
    if has_dockerfile:
      raise DockerfileError(
          'There is a Dockerfile in the current directory, and the runtime '
          'field in {0} is currently set to [runtime: {1}]. To use your '
          'Dockerfile to build a custom runtime, set the runtime field to '
          '[runtime: custom]. To continue using the [{1}] runtime, please '
          'remove the Dockerfile from this directory.'.format(info.file,
```

On the other hand the `gcloud beta app deploy` does not do this verification at all (assuming I reviewed the correct code):

```
if runtime == 'custom' and self in (self.ALWAYS,
                                    self.WHITELIST_BETA,
                                    self.WHITELIST_GA):
  return needs_dockerfile
```

In conclusion, the `.gcloudignore` will prevent some files/folder to be uploaded but not will be considered when doing some pre-checks of this command. In this case a `Dockerfile` should be considered since it could be part of the deployment.